# What does this checkmark mean in the course listing screen?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

Started playing through the levels and trying to pick up everything I see along the way so I don't have to go back and revisit the levels.

First course so far so good.

[image]
*First course complete*

The second course, I picked up everything, or so I thought. The course listing doesn't have a checkmark for this course.

[image]
*Where's my checkmark?*

I guess I didn't get everything, despite getting the wonder seeds, the purple coins, and the top of the flagpole. The course seems pretty complex in terms of things happening in the level so I could see there could be other things hidden.

So what does this checkmark mean?

Comment: I feel like I'm blind, what checkbox are you talking about?

Comment: There's a big faint green circle and checkmark that appears right behind the wonder seeds. The first picture has it, the second doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It still means that you got everything in the course.

In this case, it turns out there was a hidden flagpole that could be found in this course so I didn't have everything yet. Reaching the other pole will give you a wonder seed for your efforts.

[image]
*Got it*

There were two wonder seeds listed initially but it turns out there were three.